# Display default background color of ListView Item in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I am working on Windows 10 ListView and I want to display ListView Item default background color as White and when select then gray. I tried following Style but  it didn't set default as White. It works when selected.

```
<Style x:Key="TestListViewContainerStyle"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter SelectedBackground="#E9E9E9"
                                       PlaceholderBackground="White"
                                       Background="White"/>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Comment: Try this `<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/></Style>`

Comment: No.I havent worked on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Background` is seperate from the `Template`. Good practice to add all the relevant styles in your `ListViewItemPresenter`. Hope that helps

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <ListViewItemPresenter
         ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
         SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"
          CheckBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
          DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
          FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
          FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
          PlaceholderBackground="White"
          PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
          PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedBackground="#E9E9E9"
          SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"
          SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush}"
          PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
          SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush}"
          DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
          DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
          ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
          ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          CheckMode="Inline"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```