# Access to ListBox item after databinding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `ListBox` where I defined a `DataTemplate` for its items:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And the class I use to add elements into the `ListBox` is the following:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name
    { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to change the background of the `ListBox` item, when for example the item has been selected:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        var item = e.AddedItems.First() as MyItem;
    }
}
```

the problem is that the item is of type `MyItem`, while I need access to the `Border` and `TextBlock` objects as well.

Comment: is your app UWP or WPF?

Comment: @Pikoh I'm asking for UWP.

Comment: ups just realized it. Sorry

Comment: does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568516/display-default-background-color-of-listview-item-in-windows-10-uwp/37569540#37569540) help

Comment: To get a `TextBlock` inside an template and change it's properties in code you should use `FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117944/listbox-items-return-string-when-datatemplate-is-button

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f91dfdb-41cc-42ca-9635-7666c1b99813/uwpxaml-change-background-color-of-listbox-selected-item?forum=wpdevelop)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fancy `RelativeSource` binding on your `Border` style:

```
<Border.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

This will create a `DataTrigger` that will bind to the `IsSelected` property of the parent `ListBoxItem`, when it is selected then it will set the background colour of the `Border` to `Pink`.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is that the item is of type MyItem, while I need access to the Border and TextBlock objects as well.

If you just want to change the background when item is selected, you can refer to the answers in the comments and @Mike Eason's answer.

But I think your main purpose here is to get the `Border` control in your selected item using `SelectionChanged` event of `ListBox`. As @S.Akbari offered, you can use `VisualTreeHelper` to find the border, but there is other easier method here you can use for example.

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var container = listBox.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
    var border = container.ContentTemplateRoot as Border;
    border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);
}
```

Using [ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem.aspx) can help you to find the container corresponding to the specified item, and then since your `Border` is the root control in your `DataTemplate`, we can use [ContentControl.ContentTemplateRoot property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateroot.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the root element of the data template specified by `ContentTemplate` property.